# How can I precede a group of many tags with a direct children selector only once in SASS?

Tags: sass

Is there any way to use only one direct children remark in the following?

```
.wrap {
    > h1,  > h2, > h3, > h4, > h5 {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Through the accepted answer below, I ended up using this:

```
.wrap > {
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use a SASS function loop:

**SASS:**

```
@function headings($from:1, $to:6) {
    @if $from == $to {
        @return 'h#{$from}';
    } @else {
        @return 'h#{$from},' + headings($from+1, $to);
    }
}

.wrap {    
    #{headings(1,6)} {
      color: white;
    }
}
```

The arguments in the function declaration ($from:1, $to:6) you can change to suit your needs when you call the function further down the line. For example, if you want just h1, h2, h3, h4 elements, you'd update `#{headings(1,6)` to `#{headings(1,4)`.

**Output CSS:**

```
.wrap h1, .wrap h2, .wrap h3, .wrap h4, .wrap h5, .wrap h6 {
  color: white; }
```

Although the above won't reduce how much you actually write, writing the function makes the process a lot less repetitive if you need to declare headings in the future...

EDIT: Further to the above, for the output CSS to only have direct descendants, please use below:

```
.wrap > {    
    #{headings(1,6)} {
      color: white;
    }
}
```

**Output CSS:**

```
.wrap > h1, .wrap > h2, .wrap > h3, .wrap > h4, .wrap > h5, .wrap > h6 {
  color: white; }
```

Comment: I like that I can tuck away the function into a mixins file. Where would I then place the > child operator in your example?

Comment: I've learned a lot from your edits. Thank you for taking the time to assist me. I am using your code throughout my project and found your code helpful.